# When I want post a tweet on my tweet page, it returns undefined instead of the actuall tweet content

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, django

I'm following a Create a (Twitter-like App with Python Django JavaScript and React)tutorial. yesterday when I save the code and close the VS code the home page was like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/if7dF.png)

and today when I run the code I realize that all of my tweets were changed and now it shows me this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2EAO.png)

and the code thath handle tweets in templetes:

```
    enter c{% extends 'tweets\base.html' %}
{% block head_title %}
what a nice concept!
{% endblock head_title %}

{% block content %}

<div class='row text-center'>
    <div class='col'>
        <h1>Welcom to Tweet</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='row mb-3'>
    <div class='col-md-4 mx-auto col-10'>
        <form class='form' id='tweet-create-form' method='POST' action='/create-tweet'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type='hidden' value='/' name='next' />
            <textarea class='form-cntrol' name='content' placeholder="Your tweet..." ></textarea>
            <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Tweet</button>>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='row' id='tweets'>
    Loading...
</div>
<script>

function handleTweetCreateFormDidSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    const myForm = event.target
    const myFormData = new FormData(myForm)
    const url = myForm.getAttribute("action")
    const method = myForm.getAttribute("method")
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    const responseType = "json"
    xhr.responseType = responseType
    xhr.open(method, url)
    xhr.setRequestHeader("HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH", "XMLHttpRequest")
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 201) {
            const newTweetJson = xhr.response
            console.log(newTweetJson.likes)
            const newTweetElement = formatTweetElement(newTweetJson)
            console.log(newTweetElement)
            tweetsContainerElement.prepend(newTweetElement)
        }
        
    }
    xhr.send(myFormData)
}

const tweetCreateFormEl = document.getElementById("tweet-create-form")
tweetCreateFormEl.addEventListener("submit", handleTweetCreateFormDidSubmit)


const tweetsContainerElement = document.getElementById("tweets") 

function loadTweets(tweetsElement) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    const method = 'GET' // "POST"
    const url = "/tweets"
    const responseType = "json"
    xhr.responseType = responseType
    xhr.open(method, url)
    xhr.onload = function() {
        const serverResponse = xhr.response
        const listedItems = serverResponse.response // array
        var finalTweetStr = ""
        var i;
        for (i=0;i<listedItems.length; i++) {
            var tweetObj = listedItems[i]
            var currentItem = formatTweetElement(tweetObj)
            finalTweetStr += currentItem
        }
        tweetsElement.innerHTML = finalTweetStr
    }
    xhr.send()
}
loadTweets(tweetsContainerElement)

function handleDidLike (tweet_id, currentCount) {
    console.log(tweet_id, currentCount)
    return 
}

function LikeBtn(tweet) {
    return "<button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' onclick=handleDidLike(" + 
    tweet.id + "," + tweet.likes + ")>" + tweet.likes + " Likes</button>"
}

function formatTweetElement(tweet) {
    var formattedTweet = "<div class='col-12 col-md-10 mx-auto border rounded py-3 mb-4 tweet' id='tweet- 
    ``" + tweet.id 
    + "'><p>" + tweet.content + 
        "</p><div class='btn-group'>" + LikeBtn(tweet) +
        "</div></div>"
    return formattedTweet
}



</script>
{% endblock content %}ode here
```

Is this a problem with my code or chrome's?